# how do I work with indefinite data gotten from user input in python?

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python and have gotten stuck in a project I am working on. I am writing a program that's capable of calculating the CGPA of a student. I have written the code (please see below) to the point where it receives all necessary information from user. My problem now is to use this data gotten from user to actually calculate the CGPA.

The Code:

```
print ("THIS PROGRAMME CALCULATES YOUR GPA AND CGPA")

fullname=str(input("ENTER YOUR FULLNAME HERE:"))

while True:
    try:
        no_of_semesters=int(input("HOW MANY SEMESTER(s) DO YOU INTEND CHECKING CGPA FOR?:"))
        break
    except:
        print("That is not a number!")
        
credit_unit_gotten=0

for number in range(int(no_of_semesters)):
    while True:
        try:
            no_of_courses=int(input("HOW MANY COURSES IN SEMESTER "+str(number+1)+":"))
            break
        except:
            print("That is not a number!")    
    
    for x in range(int(no_of_courses)):
        credit_unit, grade=input("HOW MANY CREDIT UNIT AND  AND GRADE IN COURSE (please seperate with comma [,]) "+str(x+1)+" OF SEMESTER "+str(number+1)+":").split(",")
               
                
print(grade,credit_unit)
        
        
grade=str(input("INPUT GRADE :"))
if grade=="a":
    y=5
elif grade=="b":
    y=4
elif grade=="c":
    y=3
elif grade=="d":
    y=2
elif grade=="e":
    y=1
else:
    y=0
   
print(grade,y)
```

Comment: In the for loop, *accumulate* each `credit_unit, grade` in a container like a list; then you can iterate over that container and do the calcs. Or you could keep a running total of grade and credit_unit in that for loop; each time you get a new input, add to the totals; then do the calcs when user entry is done.

Comment: Hi @wwii, really grateful for your suggestion, it was really helpful though it took me some time to do. I have been able to create a list for **credit_unit and grade**, and I have also learn to use the for loop with zip() to multiply it.  This works perfectly when calculating the GPA of a semester, however it doesnt when calculating for more than one semesters, when trying to run 2 or more semesters it gives the GPA of the last semester instead of the CGPA of all semesters.